# Intellij 14, Lambda expressions buggy, shows error despite no compiler errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When using lambdas in Intellij 14 for interfaces that throws an exception, Intellij **incorrectly highlights them as errors.**

I have been trying to reproduce the error in simpler form but it hasn't been easy. I am forced now to replace my lambdas with anonymous inner classes.

Ok, I was able to figure out the root issue here, and was able to reproduce a working example:

```
    // Works fine
    public static void exampleOne() throws IOException {

            methodOne();

            methodTwo(() -> {

            });

    }

    // Works fine
    public static void exampleTwo() throws IOException {

            // IOException bubbles up here, which is thrown by the method signature
            methodTwo(() -> {
                    methodOne(); // throws IOException
            });
    }

    // Works fine
    public static void exampleThree() throws IOException {

            methodTwo(() -> {
                    methodOne();

                    methodTwo(() -> {

                    });
            });
    }

    // !!!!!! Error !!!!!!!!
    public static void exampleFour() throws IOException {

            methodTwo(() -> {
                    methodOne();

                    methodThree(() -> {

                    });
            });


            // Error here!

            // It appears as if methodOne throws IOException, which should bubble up, and then methodThree call does not throw anything but Intellij gets confused
            // If we look at exampleThree then we can see that a call to the same as the one we called first methodTwo does not yield any problems.

            // This error does not exist in Intellij 13 and compiles fine with Java.

            // Error type cannot be ignored in Intellij which is a major issue!
    }

    // Works fine
    public static void exampleFourAnonymous() throws IOException {

            methodTwo(new Callable<IOException>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call() throws IOException {
                            methodOne();

                            methodThree(() -> {

                            });
                    }
            });
    }

    public static interface Callable<E extends Throwable> {
            void call() throws E;
    }

    public static void methodOne() throws IOException {
    }

    public static <E extends Throwable> void methodTwo(Callable<E> lambda) throws E {
            lambda.call();
    }

    public static <E extends Throwable> void methodThree(Callable<E> lambda) throws E {
            lambda.call();
    }
```

This error does not exist in Intellij 13.

Is this a valid error message?

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour. Probably you should submit this bug to IntelliJ bugtracker.

Comment: I can't remember my password, and I never get any love, attention or discussion there. I find it easier to just put it up here, and have someone pick it up if it is valid.

Comment: This appears to be off-topic because it isn't a question.

Comment: @AlanStokes added a question

Comment: Does not happen in NetBeans. IntelliJ does not seem to impose the restriction to IOException at the outset of methodThree's parameter. This expected vs. derived type behavior has become constantly redesigned in java. File a bug report to solve this incompatibility.

Comment: YouTrack has a "restore password" feature. Please do file this as a bug. StackOverlow is not an issue tracker.

Comment: @yole done: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134803

Comment: @JoopEggen Doesn't happen in Intellij 13 either.

Comment: @yole I also created this related bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134808

Comment: Thanks for filing the issue @momo!

Comment: Now fixed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134808

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now fixed: youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134808